# Find data of the UWP audio output

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

The other day while I was testing AudioGraph in UWP I had found a data that was not constant ... but that oscillated that I think was the oscillation of frequencies or something like that, that now I can not find any more, I do not remember if it was of: AudioGraph, AudioFileInputNode or AudioDeviceOutputNode (I think AudioDeviceOutputNode but I'm not sure).

It was a value that oscillated and was high around 250000 (something similar).

I'm interested in finding that value and then calculating the various frequencies ...

(The value oscillate as graph.LatencyInSamples but was higher .. (timer_tick method))

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnChooseFile" Content="Choose File" Click="btnChooseFile_Click" Height="32" Width="250" />
        <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="Play - Stop" Click="btnStop_Click" Height="32" Width="250" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txbLevel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private AudioGraph graph;
    private AudioFileInputNode fileInputNode;
    private AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutputNode;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    bool playing = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1);
        timer.Tick += timer_tick;
    }

    private void timer_tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        txbLevel.Text = graph.LatencyInSamples.ToString();
    }

    private async void btnChooseFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await CreateAudioGraph();
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
        filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        CreateAudioFileInputNodeResult fileInputResult = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(file);
        fileInputNode = fileInputResult.FileInputNode;
        fileInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);
        graph.Start();
        timer.Start();
        playing = true;
    }

    private async Task CreateAudioGraph()
    {
        AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
        graph = result.Graph;
        CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult outputDeviceNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        deviceOutputNode = outputDeviceNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (playing)
        {
            graph.Stop();
            playing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            graph.Start();
            playing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A help?

Thank you very much..!

Comment: I'm confused about your issue, could you please detail what are you actually looking for?

Comment: I look for the value that then allows me to calculate the frequencies db to make an AdioSpectrum